# Android AdMob displayed insecure content

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

I'm trying to setup AdMob in my Android application and everything was working great until I tried it out on live devices. On all testing everything worked fine but after building for release and testing on some real devices I can't seem to get any ads to display.

In the logcat I see the following:

```
06-19 08:20:00.333: W/Ads(765): JS: The page at about:blank displayed
insecure content from
gmsg://mobileads.google.com/loadAdURL?drt_include=1&request_scenario=online_request&type=adsense&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogleads.g.doubleclick.net%3A80%2Fpagead%2Fads%3Fseq_num%3D2%26rm%3D0%26js%3Dafma-sdk-a-v5050000.4452000.1%26eid%3D46621036%26hl%3Den%26smart_w%3Dfull%26gnt%3D8%26ma%3D0%26carrier%3D310410%26u_sd%3D2%26sp%3D0%26cnt%3D1%26muv%3D11%26riv%3D0%26ms%3DAabTiRkN-TWtZD6h0dgJrRLnO71LByFeBR4rsRvp7No0r7clpBJ9AjfI6tnZUcqqYnIvYCkY_gF6Ydca0k48bWpabbNvDNRupg5bFqRFpKama3sHrF12GdI2xXEboP0XkZFZxotj0eVOUTZupQvQZqYTK1Eu3MFpyMANdfhO8KGRnipiqsEuUe7kBVKlYCztSzt9scDxe5kzoKlHFM-N3KU_9wc7kG-38iCR9vwVcsRVBV5Rlog4XQlwL5VSTiBS9RNvVR4qtRh5UYzUP9w_AdqIlN7VOCIgL7P2gWns65-HH83WyCY03q1eNZKRZE_gNCzTmKCMj1UpSYKJPKl_DA%26mv%3D80280020.com.android.vending%26format%3D360x50_as%26smart_h%3Dauto%26coh%3D1%26gl%3DUS%26am%3D0%26u_w%3D360%26u_h%3D592%26msid%3Dcom.shotzoom.golfshot2%26an%3D35.android.com.shotzoom.golfshot2%26net%3Dwi%26u_audio%3D3%26u_so%3Dp%26preqs%3D1%26support_transparent_background%3Dtrue%26pimp%3D0%26currts%3D69048595%26pclick%3D0%26basets%3D69046460%26bisch%3Dtrue%26blev%3D0.9900000095367432%26cans%3D5%26canm%3Dfalse%26output%3Dhtml%26region%3Dmobile_app%26u_tz%3D-420%26url%3D35.android.com.shotzoom.golfshot2.adsenseformobileapps.com%26client%3Dca-mb-app-pub-6679563818464867%26slotname%3D9075894439%26askip%3D1%26gsb%3Dwi%26caps%3DinlineVideo_interactiveVideo_mraid1_th_autoplay_mediation_av_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di%26jsv%3D92%26urll%3D1130&base_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogleads.g.doubleclick.net%3A80%2Fpagead%2Fads&use_webview_loadurl=0&google.afma.Notify_dt=1403191200323.
06-19 08:20:00.333: W/Ads(765):  (null:1) 06-19 08:20:00.333: W/Web
Console(765): The page at about:blank displayed insecure content from
gmsg://mobileads.google.com/loadAdURL?drt_include=1&request_scenario=online_request&type=adsense&url=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogleads.g.doubleclick.net%3A80%2Fpagead%2Fads%3Fseq_num%3D2%26rm%3D0%26js%3Dafma-sdk-a-v5050000.4452000.1%26eid%3D46621036%26hl%3Den%26smart_w%3Dfull%26gnt%3D8%26ma%3D0%26carrier%3D310410%26u_sd%3D2%26sp%3D0%26cnt%3D1%26muv%3D11%26riv%3D0%26ms%3DAabTiRkN-TWtZD6h0dgJrRLnO71LByFeBR4rsRvp7No0r7clpBJ9AjfI6tnZUcqqYnIvYCkY_gF6Ydca0k48bWpabbNvDNRupg5bFqRFpKama3sHrF12GdI2xXEboP0XkZFZxotj0eVOUTZupQvQZqYTK1Eu3MFpyMANdfhO8KGRnipiqsEuUe7kBVKlYCztSzt9scDxe5kzoKlHFM-N3KU_9wc7kG-38iCR9vwVcsRVBV5Rlog4XQlwL5VSTiBS9RNvVR4qtRh5UYzUP9w_AdqIlN7VOCIgL7P2gWns65-HH83WyCY03q1eNZKRZE_gNCzTmKCMj1UpSYKJPKl_DA%26mv%3D80280020.com.android.vending%26format%3D360x50_as%26smart_h%3Dauto%26coh%3D1%26gl%3DUS%26am%3D0%26u_w%3D360%26u_h%3D592%26msid%3Dcom.shotzoom.golfshot2%26an%3D35.android.com.shotzoom.golfshot2%26net%3Dwi%26u_audio%3D3%26u_so%3Dp%26preqs%3D1%26support_transparent_background%3Dtrue%26pimp%3D0%26currts%3D69048595%26pclick%3D0%26basets%3D69046460%26bisch%3Dtrue%26blev%3D0.9900000095367432%26cans%3D5%26canm%3Dfalse%26output%3Dhtml%26region%3Dmobile_app%26u_tz%3D-420%26url%3D35.android.com.shotzoom.golfshot2.adsenseformobileapps.com%26client%3Dca-mb-app-pub-6679563818464867%26slotname%3D9075894439%26askip%3D1%26gsb%3Dwi%26caps%3DinlineVideo_interactiveVideo_mraid1_th_autoplay_mediation_av_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di%26jsv%3D92%26urll%3D1130&base_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogleads.g.doubleclick.net%3A80%2Fpagead%2Fads&use_webview_loadurl=0&google.afma.Notify_dt=1403191200323.
06-19 08:20:00.333: W/Web Console(765):  at null:1 06-19 08:20:00.372:
W/Ads(765): JS: The page at
https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html
displayed insecure content from
file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png. 06-19 08:20:00.372:
W/Ads(765):  (null:1) 06-19 08:20:00.372: W/Web Console(765): The page
at
https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/static/mad/sdk/native/sdk-core-v40.html
displayed insecure content from
file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png. 06-19 08:20:00.372:
W/Web Console(765):  at null:1 06-19 08:20:00.747: I/Ads(31911): No
fill from ad server. 06-19 08:20:00.755: W/Ads(31911): Failed to load
ad: 3
```

If the "no fill from ad server" is the reason I see these errors then that's totally fine.  I just want to make sure that the other messages aren't an indication that I'm doing something wrong and will never get an ad to populate.

Searching the interwebs for this the only suggestion I found was to ensure proguard was working properly but I'm not using proguard at this time so I don't think that'll be a factor

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm getting the same warning in logcat. I guess it's not a problem in your or my implementation, the problem is rather that the served ads use 'insecure' javascript stuff. I think it's up to Google to take care of that issue.

Comment: I have same message, but app crash after it. Stack trace contains calls inside google play service library, I can not debug it.

Answer (score 1):

Update your xml layout according to new policy of AdMob. AdView must be placed correctly, ads should not be placed over the other application content.

Please read admob updated publisher policy and guidelines [here](https://support.google.com/admob/v2/answer/2936217).

Answer (score 0):

I think it could relate to Google Play Services installed or not. Maybe they are just logs from Google implementation.

I got these logs on emulator WITHOUT Google Play Services installed.

Problem GONE on emulator which have Google Play Services.

Answer (score -2):

Turns out the error occurred because I was using SMART_BANNER for the adSize instead of BANNER, might be something to try for other people encountering this message

EDIT:

Based upon the discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/g6tSDG4QOhE) it was an issue on AdMob's end in relation to something they were testing out. Moving back to BANNER instead of SMART_BANNER was still necessary for me to get any ad fill but the errors seemed to be unrelated.

Comment: So the did your revert to BANNER to get rid of this problem?

Comment: I have the same problem now with unity, on android. This error message also murders my framerate. I'm only getting it on the htc onex+ tho. I was also using SMART_BANNER, but switching to BANNER did not solve this issue.